# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: android, google-maps, algolia

I want to use Algolia in my app for geo search.

When I copy the sample project([icebnb](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/tree/master/icebnb)) files to my project.

I already cleared some error bug from instant search module by the help of stack overflow helpers.

It raises an error when I open the activity (runtime).

I am facing this error and suffering from long time. Please help me.

```
09-27 14:44:57.244 29793-29793/com.google.tho.saw E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.ParseContextImpl.parse(ParseContextImpl.java:38)
   at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:502)
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getObjectFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:40)
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getStringFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:22)
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:458)
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:398)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1618)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4702)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

   at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.<clinit>(JsonContext.java:41)
   at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.ParseContextImpl.parse(ParseContextImpl.java:38) 
   at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:502) 
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getObjectFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:40) 
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getStringFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:22) 
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:458) 
   at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:398) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1618) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4702) 
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791) 
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591) 
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560) 
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing library for class `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

Try adding following depending in your **`app/build.gradle`** file.

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.24'
```

OR

You can also download [slf4j jar](https://www.slf4j.org/download.html) file and then include in app/build.gradle as:

```
compile files('libs/slf4j.jar'); //You can change jar name here
```

Comment: After adding the library i sync and clean and build project also.
Then also same error raising.
i notise one line 
09-27 15:55:01.422 32151-32151/com.google.tho.saw E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method jc.a

Comment: mainly in 4 lines show blue color link.

                                                                    1.at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getObjectFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:40)
                                                                    2.at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getStringFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:22)

Comment: 3. at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:458)
                                                                  4.  at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:398)

Comment: Are you running proguard enabled build?

Comment: i cant understand. pls

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: Is that u ask bro ?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.google.tho.saw"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

Comment: from my app.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

What version of InstantSearch Android/IceBNB are you using?

- Running the [current version of IceBNB](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/tree/master/icebnb) works as expected, the only way I can reproduce your situation is by *manually removing* SLF4J from InstantSearch:

  ```
  compile ("com.algolia:instantsearch-android:$VERSION_INSTANTSEARCH") {
      exclude group: "org.slf4j"
  }
  ```

This would trigger the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` that you report. But unless you do remove `SLF4J` manually, you should not need anything to have the example apps working.

- The accepted answer's suggestion only makes sense if you had removed `SLF4J` in the first place.

Can you share a setup which triggers the error?